# Append value to array inside dictionary (useState) react js

Tags: reactjs, append, use-state

I have a useState like this `const [okLetters, setOkLetters] = useState({green: [], yellow: []})`

I want to append values to each list under a condition

When I use `setOkLetters({green: [...okLetters.green, grid[currAttempt.currRow][i]]` and log okLetters to the console, no matter how many green letters there are, only one will be appended.

```
{green: Array(1), yellow: Array(0)}
green: ['A']
yellow: []
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

How can I append values to a list in this dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your updates are immutable, your syntax for updating state should be closer to

```
setOkLetters({...okLetters, green: [...okLetters.green, grid[currAttempt.currRow][i]]});
```

However, your current approach should be working as intended in appending letters to the `green` array. When/where are you logging `okLetters`? I'm wondering if there's an issue or if condition elsewhere that is causing only one green letter to be appended.

Comment: To answer your question, yes there is a condition that causes green letters to be appended, but I have put a print statement inside this condition to see if it works and it does.

Comment: Without more information, I'm afraid I'm not sure how to help you. I've implemented an example using both your and my syntax and they are both appending multiple values to the array